# .htaccess use subdirectories files

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi all i am purely newbie to right .htaccess files. The issue is,

My base directory is `http://localhost/mvctask/`and i want to use the files of sub directory `sub`.
for example:

`http://localhost/mvctask/` will be using  `http://localhost/mvctask/sub/login.php` instead `http://localhost/mvctask/login.php`.

While url remain same as `http://localhost/mvctask/`. I need it to do without using rewrite-rules.
Please any help.

**Edit:**
I changed the index.php to login.php in edit. just because there is option to use DirectoryIndex mysubdir/index.php to change index .

Comment: If you can't use mod-rewrite then point your virtual host to sub-folder

Comment: I want to use only specific files of sub folder not all, will it be recommended?

Comment: so in this case you must use mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution that same `DirectoryIndex` is working for all files. While previously i assumed that it works only for index files (may be i confused due to it's name :P ).

`DirectoryIndex mysubdir/login.php`